# How to echo row (datetime) with other format?

Tags: php

Part of PHP code

```
[" .$row["comment_datetime"] . "]
```

The rest of the PHP will not put here because anyone can create own example (query, SQL connect, etc. ...)

The echo output:

> [YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strtotime:

```
<?php
  echo date('d - m - Y', strtotime($row["comment_datetime"]));
?>
```